# Changing Android alias produces "App has stopped working" error even though it changes it correctly in emulator in Android API 25

Tags: android, alias

I've the following code that changes the default name of my application and its related icon to a new name and icon.

```
try {

            getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    new ComponentName("com.applications.social.myapp", "com.applications.social.myapp.MainActivityFlavorOne"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


            getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    new ComponentName("com.applications.social.myapp", "com.applications.social.myapp.MainActivityFlavorZero"),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }    


        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

On the other hand this is how the alias are defined on manifest file:

```
   <activity-alias
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivityFlavorZero"
            android:label="MyLabel"
            android:icon="@mipmap/notification_icon"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:targetActivity="com.applications.social.myapp.InstallationActivity"
            android:windowAnimationStyle="@null"
            android:windowBackground="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>



        <activity-alias
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="MyLabel2"
            android:name=".MainActivityFlavorOne"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/lantern"
            android:targetActivity="com.applications.social.myapp.InstallationActivity"
            android:windowAnimationStyle="@null"
            android:windowBackground="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

There are several things that make me think it's an emulator bug rather than a fail in the code, these ones:

1) Problem appears, so far, in emulator in Android API 25, but the same code works fine, in physical devices with APIs 19 and 23, and in emulator with API 22 and 24.

2) The opposite code (the one that would change from MainActivityFlavorOne to MainActivityFlavorZero) always works.

3) The error happens from the first time the change MainActivityFlavorOne is set, on its first set it always works.

4) Even though the error appears, the icon and name of the app is changed in apps screen (and does offer its required behavior), so it's not that the code isn't working for practical purposes, just that the error appears anyway once the rest of the behavior expected due to the code happens.

But anyway, I'm asking to see if someone has run into something similar and can suggest ways to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't call this exactly a "real" solution, but for my case is enough.

By setting target sdk version to 24 and building with it the app doesn't give that error any longer, so it's clear that's something API dependent.